Can vertex groups be passed to subsequent modifiers in Geometry Nodes?
Can the vertex group attributes be passed to subsequent modifiers in Geometry Nodes? For me, the vertex groups are lost when I instantiate the instance meshes (cubes in my example).



why don't you just move the bevel modifier before the gn modifier?

Just as @Chris said, my thoughts exactly. Or instead of using a vertex group, there are other methods for beveling as well: use a bevel weight on the edges. This will also work when you place the Bevel modifier after the GN modifier, however then you will have to use a Realize Instances node (but this does not help for vertex groups, in this case I would change the order as well).

May I recommend to read these posts : get Vertex Group to survive Geometry Nodes  and Transfer (float) vertex-attribute to vertex-weight, to allow GeoNodes to control subsequent Armature binding ?

I was just interested in the possibility transferring vertex group data for the use in subsequent modifiers. I'll read the link by StefLAncien. Thank you.
